# What java library to extract message content from a WSDL?

Tags: java, wsdl, wsdl4j

I have to extract the content of the messages of a WSDL to build a view in excel sheet of the hierarchy of blocks and data fields. My objective is to have one line per block or field with the name, datatype, restrictions, mandatory or not, etc...
To perform this task, I look for a java library and samples or a tutorial.

I tried with WSDL4J and easyWSDL but I feel that these libraries are too complex for my need and difficult to leverage with the available documentation...

Can anyone give me an advise ?

PS : the subject of my answer isn't about generate the excel sheet

Answer (score 1):

Those libraries would help you to generate client classes for your webservice, but I don't think they would help you in your purpose.  Instead of that I suggest that, for example, you use dom4j or jdom to parse the WSDLs (whigh should be correct xml documents) and extract the information you need from them by using XPath queries

http://www.jdom.org/

http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/